# Mirror in Shul?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, avodah-zarah, synagogue, architecture-design

Is a mirror allowed in shul if it is hanging on a wall that no one faces when they daven?

It feels wrong to me, but I cannot find a source stating that it is explicitly forbidden since no one is praying directly in front of it.